# gnome-keyring-daemon spams system journal

Tags: 18.04, gnome, login, nextcloud

My systemd journal is being spammed with messages from gnome-keyring-daemon, 3-4 log entries per second:

```
Nov 14 10:55:40 flunder gnome-keyring-daemon[16099]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/287, but it's already registered
Nov 14 10:55:40 flunder gnome-keyring-daemon[16099]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/288, but it's already registered
```

Killing gnome-keyring-daemon didn't help, nor did restarting the machine.

This is quite annoying and wasteful, and I have no idea what it's trying to tell me or how to remove that duplicate login item. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: this is actually caused by the Nextcloud desktop client. The duplicate entries are the Nextcloud passwords, and when I stop the client, the spam also stops.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-keyring/issues/24

Comment: And I've seen related comments which suggest to uninstall `dbus-user-session`, but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*sigh* found the issue after all: it's a bug in Nextcloud 2.6.1, see https://github.com/nextcloud/desktop/issues/1592